# Why can't people write questions?

Tags: discussion

It's a generalisation, but I'm pretty sure the majority of users' headlines aren't actually in the form of a question, and when they are, the majority don't end with a question mark.

Why is this, and why doesn't the SO parser check for the presence of a question mark? It seems to check and alert for certain keywords which are indicative of 'bad' questions.

Comment: This definitely isn't limited to our site - on many of the other sites the title will state the problem rather than ask for the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not actually *required* that the title be a question, though it is generally better if it is.

[Should question titles be phrased as questions? (A straw poll)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19999/should-question-titles-be-phrased-as-questions-a-straw-poll)

[Is it better for SEO for question titles to actually be questions (grammatically speaking)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19950/is-it-better-for-seo-for-question-titles-to-actually-be-questions-grammatically)

Comment: Fair enough, and I'll go along with those points when editing question titles. It does annnoy me when they actually *are* questions, but miss off the question mark though.